# where to find applicationContext.xml after install it

Tags: rpm

I installed the project using `rpm`, then found out there was a typo in the `application.xml` file. then i searched the `application.xml` but could not it? its not in

```
/etc/tmo/myservice/
```

or

```
/usr/tmo/myservice/
```

where can I find it? Thanks.

Comment: what are you talking about? which project?

Answer (score 0):

It is completely unclear to me what you mean, so I try to answer on a very general level.

If you have a .rpm and want to know what is contained in it, you can either do

```
rpm -q -lv <packet name>
```

for querying installed packets, or

```
rpm -qp -lv <rpm file name>
```

for querying .rpm files you want to inspect without installing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a file in Linux and you know the name (or part of it) of the file, you can do this:

> find / -name "filename.extension"

And you can use wildcards:

> find / -name "file*"